# How can I add several methods to two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

My homework problem tells me to create arrays two called studentName and studentScore and they both accept data entered. They have methods which

1. return the sum of the scores in the array
2. return the average of the score
3. return the highest value and print the highest value along with the student who earned the highest value
4. return the lowest value and print the lowest value along with the student with the lowest value
5. determine the average score and return students who earned a score the average
6. determine the lowest score and return students who earned a score below the average

I've tried completing the first step by declaring the "sum."

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
         public class Homewor5 {
         public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          int studentScore = scan.nextInt();
           int sum = 0;
            while( studentScore > 0 )
            {sum = sum + studentScore;}
            System.out.println("Enter student's score " +           
            studentScore);
            for(i = 0; i <= studentScore; i ++);
            char studentsName = (char) System.in.read();
            System.out.println("Enter student's name " + 
            studentsName);
```

Comment: You cannot add methods to the array, you can build a method within a class that owns the array to calculate the values.

Comment: "*They have methods which....*" - Arrays do not have methods.

Comment: I think you should start with writing a code to consume data from the input and load it to two arrays. First studentName array and second studentScore. 
Then you should operate on these arrays to get tasks done.

Comment: Try - Create a new class which extends array class and implement the methods.